# Manage Clients grid - client name blank

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, grid

After following [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13878/how-to-make-last-name-optional-in-magento-1-8) clients that register trough `/customer/account/create/` successfully is not required to input a lastname, but their whole name won't show on the client grid. If the lastname is changed, it reappears.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it looks like the Grid.php was showing the whole name instead of first and lastname. So I guess when lastname isn't present it just goes blank. A bit weird. Just overrode to `/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php` and commented out the name column:

```
    $this->addColumn('firstname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
        'index'     => 'firstname'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('lastname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Name'),
        'index'     => 'lastname'
    ));
    /*$this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));*/
```