# company name in place of first/last name for Business customer group?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, forms, register

How can i make the customer group **Business** request a `Company Name` instead of
`First Name` or `Last Name`. this way when signing up a company i can put in the company info since there wont be any first/last name. i then need the company name to be shown anywhere first/last name is usually shown (invoices, account area, ETC.)

Comment: How would you know the group before registering the customer?

Comment: @mbalparda Well business customers are registered from the backend by me, while regular customers can register through the frontend registration page

Comment: @Nxlevel can you confirm this worked?  I want to do the same thing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your Magento version?

The idea how to achieve your goal is: Make the last name field optional and hide it, and change the first name label to company. So the first name value of the customer is company name that customer entered, and company name will display on everywhere first name field should be.

So first thing first, make last name field optional:

1. [How to make last name optional in Magento 1.8](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13878/how-to-make-last-name-optional-in-magento-1-8) , Magento 1.7 eva attributes table name is `eva_attribute`, you can find the `attribute_code = 'lastname'`
2. Hide last name field in everywhere(disallowed customer enter last name), there are 4 files should update(maybe more files):

   - `app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/customer/form/register.phtml`

   > Has the HTML form for initial registration Note: this file will also be used for a one-shot database extension

   - `app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/customer/form/edit.phtml`

   > Has the HTML form for edit by customers

   - `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Entity/Setup.php`

   > Has an array full of customer attributes to use for registration

   - `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml`

   > Has a description of fields to be used in the forms

   - `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`

   > For checkbox option

   Reference: [Custom Account/Registration Fields](http://www.magento.cc/custom-accountregistration-fields.html)
3. After you update the files, you should register and test the changes is working or not. Test the email content, place order and invoice etc, make sure everywhere only display the company name.

Ohh! one more thing, GOOD LUCK!